# Two UIView with same anchor point

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, calayer

I have been trying the below code, to intersect two UIView with anchorPoint (1,0).

```
UIView *v=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50, 100, 100)];
v.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
v.layer.anchorPoint=CGPointMake(1,0);

UIView *v2=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,200,300)];
v2.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
v2.layer.anchorPoint=CGPointMake(1, 0);

[self.view addSubview:v2];
[self.view addSubview:v];
```

The output that I have with this code is as shown below.

[image: Intersect Two Views with Anchor Point]

I looking of output like red view overlaps green view and both of them having same anchor point, as show below.

[image]

Comment: is the correct output for the `frame` values in your code above? where is `P(50.f, 50.f)` on this picture? what would be the result if you comment out the `anchorPoint` lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help to describe what is happening in your example:

You are putting two rectangles on the screen of an exact size, in an exact location `(50, 50)` (relative to their origins in their top left corners)
They both have anchor points which by default are in their centres.
Imagine putting a pin in these centre points.
Now you say you actually want the pins in the top right corner not the centre.

One of two things will happen, either

1) The rectangles will stay stationary and the pins will move themselves to the top right corners `red:(150, 50)` `green:(250, 50)`, which isn't what you want.

or

2) The pins will stay stationary and the rectangles will move themselves until their top right corners are where the pins are `red pin:(100, 100)` `green pin:(150, 200)`, which also isn't what you want!

The second option is what actually happens.

According to the docs the `layer.position` is relative to the `layer.anchorPoint`, so you should try setting the `anchorPoint` to the top right corners and then set the `position` of both rectangles layers to the exact position you want. e.g.

```
UIView *v=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50, 100, 100)];
v.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
v.layer.anchorPoint=CGPointMake(1,0);
v.layer.position = CGPointMake(200, 50);

UIView *v2=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,200,300)];
v2.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
v2.layer.anchorPoint=CGPointMake(1, 0);
v2.layer.position = CGPointMake(200, 50);

[self.view addSubview:v2];
[self.view addSubview:v];
```

**Just for fun**: here is an animation to show how the rectangles get from their initial locations in `initWithFrame` to their final positions, relative to the anchor points in their centres.

```
UIView *v=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50, 100, 100)];
v.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];

UIView *v2=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,200,300)];
v2.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];

[self.view addSubview:v2];
[self.view addSubview:v];   

UIView *ap=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 10, 10)];
ap.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
ap.center = v.layer.position;

UIView *ap2=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 10, 10)];
ap2.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
ap2.center = v2.layer.position;

[self.view addSubview:ap]; 
[self.view addSubview:ap2];   

CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"anchorPoint"];
animation.duration = 2.0;
animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(1,0)];
animation.autoreverses = YES;
animation.repeatCount = 10;
[v.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"anchorPoint"];
[v2.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"anchorPoint"];
```

Comment: added an animation to illustrate :-)

Answer (score 2):

please, check the original documentation about the `anchorPoint` and a coordinate systems [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Layers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006082)

**Figure 2**  Three anchorPoint values: [image: Three anchorPoint values]

**UPDATE #1:**

(this image shows the coordinate system of OSX!)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean, you like to have the red view be the size of the overlapping area between the green view and the original red view?

If so,

```
v.frame = CGRectIntersection(v.frame, v2.frame);
```

Comment: I don't want to check whether its intersecting or not. Red Image must intersect with the Color Image, with anchor point (1,0)

Comment: Sorry andyPaul, you will have to be clearer with what you want.  The CGRectInsersectsRect returns the CGRect of the intersecting area.

Comment: Sorry you are wrong,  please go to this link https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html , CGRectIntersectsRect returns bool

Comment: My bad, was typing without Xcode open.  Still didn't take long to find the function I meant CGRectInstersection.  I still don't know if this is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for correction.The black color dot, represents anchor point. So, what I am looking is Green color and Red Color view must have **same** anchor point.